# ValidationMessageFor child span element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` that appends a span element with a text below my `id` if e.g. an email is incorrect.

In the same process i want to color my input border red. I therefore made this jQuery:

```
$("#valMsg").change(function () {
    if ($("#valMsg").children().length > 0)
    {
        $("#pwInput").css({ "border-color": "red" });
    }
    else $("#pwInput").removeAttr("style");
})
```

HTML

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control inputBx", @placeholder = "Password", @id="pwInput" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, null, new { @class="text-danger", @id="valMsg"})
```

The problem is, that it doesn't recognise anything. I can remove my if statement, whereafter it works. But by doing so, the red frame doesn't go away, if value in the input box is valid.

Comment: Does you validation message get displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework adds specific class names to your elements based on the valid state of your inputs.

A valid input has `class="valid"`, and its associated error message has `class="field-validation-valid"`

An invalid input has `class="input-validation-error"`, and its associated error message has `class="field-validation-error"`

Delete you script (and the `new { @id = ".." }` in your markup) and use style sheets to style the elements.

The defaults from `site.css` are

```
input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}
field-validation-error {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

As a side note, your scripts makes no sense since the element with `id="valMsg"` is a `<span>` which does not have a `.change()` event.